# Error: cannot call constructor

Tags: c++, linux, ns2

I have included new module to ns2 for evaluation of video transmission. I have make changes which are required to the some files like agent.h ,agent.cc, makefile and so on.
During make getting stuck with the error.
The error is:

```
myevalvid/myudp.cc: In member function ‘virtual void myUdpAgent::sendmsg(int, AppData*, const char*)’: 
myevalvid/myudp.cc:56:123: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat] 
myevalvid/myudp.cc:78:123: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat] 
make: *** No rule to make target `myevalvid/myevalvid_sink.o ', needed by `ns'.  Stop.
```

The code is

```
#include "myudp.h"
#include "rtp.h"
#include "random.h"
#include "address.h"
#include "ip.h"


static class myUdpAgentClass : public TclClass {
public:
    myUdpAgentClass() : TclClass("Agent/myUDP") {}
    TclObject* create(int, const char*const*) {
        return (new myUdpAgent());
    }
} class_myudp_agent;

myUdpAgent::myUdpAgent() : id_(0), openfile(0)
{
    bind("packetSize_", &size_);
}

void myUdpAgent::sendmsg(int nbytes, AppData* data, const char* flags)
{
    Packet *p;
    int n;
    char buf[100]; //added by smallko

    if (size_)
        n = nbytes / size_;
    else
        printf("Error: myUDP size = 0\n");

    if (nbytes == -1) {
        printf("Error:  sendmsg() for UDP should not be -1\n");
        return;
    }   

    // If they are sending data, then it must fit within a single packet.
    if (data && nbytes > size_) {
        printf("Error: data greater than maximum myUDP packet size\n");
        return;
    }

    double local_time = Scheduler::instance().clock();
    while (n-- > 0) {
        p = allocpkt();
        hdr_cmn::access(p)->size() = size_;
        hdr_rtp* rh = hdr_rtp::access(p);
        rh->flags() = 0;
        rh->seqno() = ++seqno_;
        hdr_cmn::access(p)->timestamp() = 
            (u_int32_t)(SAMPLERATE*local_time);
        hdr_cmn::access(p)->sendtime_ = local_time; // (smallko)
        if(openfile!=0){
            hdr_cmn::access(p)->frame_pkt_id_ = id_++;
            sprintf(buf, "%-16f id %-16d udp %-16d\n", local_time, hdr_cmn::access(p)->frame_pkt_id_, hdr_cmn::access(p)->size()-28);
            fwrite(buf, strlen(buf), 1, BWFile); 
            //printf("%-16f id %-16d udp %-16d\n", local_time, hdr_cmn::access(p)->frame_pkt_id_, hdr_cmn::access(p)->size()-28);
        }
        // add "beginning of talkspurt" labels (tcl/ex/test-rcvr.tcl)
        if (flags && (0 ==strcmp(flags, "NEW_BURST")))
            rh->flags() |= RTP_M;
        p->setdata(data);
        target_->recv(p);
    }
    n = nbytes % size_;
    if (n > 0) {
        p = allocpkt();
        hdr_cmn::access(p)->size() = n;
        hdr_rtp* rh = hdr_rtp::access(p);
        rh->flags() = 0;
        rh->seqno() = ++seqno_;
        hdr_cmn::access(p)->timestamp() = 
            (u_int32_t)(SAMPLERATE*local_time);
        hdr_cmn::access(p)->sendtime_ = local_time; // (smallko)
        if(openfile!=0){
            hdr_cmn::access(p)->frame_pkt_id_ = id_++;
            sprintf(buf, "%-16f id %-16d udp %-16d\n", local_time, hdr_cmn::access(p)->frame_pkt_id_, hdr_cmn::access(p)->size()-28);
            fwrite(buf, strlen(buf), 1, BWFile); 
            //printf("%-16f id %-16d udp %-16d\n", local_time, hdr_cmn::access(p)->frame_pkt_id_, hdr_cmn::access(p)->size()-28);
        }
        // add "beginning of talkspurt" labels (tcl/ex/test-rcvr.tcl)
        if (flags && (0 == strcmp(flags, "NEW_BURST")))
            rh->flags() |= RTP_M;
        p->setdata(data);
        target_->recv(p);
    }
    idle();
}

int myUdpAgent::command(int argc, const char*const* argv)
{
    if(argc ==2) {      //added by smallko
        if (strcmp(argv[1], "closefile") == 0) {
            if(openfile==1)
                fclose(BWFile);
            return (TCL_OK);
        }

    } 

    if (argc ==3) {     //added by smallko
        if (strcmp(argv[1], "set_filename") == 0) {
            strcpy(BWfile, argv[2]);
            BWFile = fopen(BWfile, "w");
            openfile=1;
            return (TCL_OK);
        }
    }

    return (UdpAgent::command(argc, argv));
}
```

please help me to sort out the error.

Comment: Edited as this is completely unrelated to "make".

Comment: @billz: The declaration declares a static variable, `class_myudp_agent`, as well as defining the class.

Comment: @MikeSeymour now I see it. good to learn. and thanks

Comment: No idea why you have `UdpAgent::UdpAgent();` there. Do you know?

Comment: For the errors on line 56 and 78, if you use `%d` you actually have to pass an `int`, or an `unsigned int` with a value in range of `int`, or a smaller integral type. The behaviour is undefined to pass anything else.  It will usually work if `int` and `long` have the same size , but you should still fix it as you don't know when you will recompile your code on another compiler or change compiler settings, and end up with differently-sized `int` and `long`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: what should I have to change then..should I use "%ld" instead of "%d"

Comment: the error message says `unsigned long`, so `%lu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you can't call a constructor directly, as this line seems to be trying to do:

```
UdpAgent::UdpAgent();
```

You probably just want to remove that line. That constructor is already being called (implicitly) at the beginning of your constructor. You could put `UdpAgent()` at the start of the initialiser list, if you want to be explicit about it.

Comment: I guess we are also assuming that `UdpAgent` is a base class of `TclClass`, else this makes even less sense

Comment: @MattMcNabb: No, I'm assuming that `UdpAgent` is a base class of `myUdpAgent` (whose definition is missing from the posted code). The error message seems to indicate that that's the case.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: made those corrections suggested by you and resolved first error. still for 2nd error please suggest exact modification.

Comment: @user257489: Use `%-16ld` rather than `%-16d` to format a `long` value. Or use `std::stringstream` or `std::to_string`, rather than mucking around with the C library.

Comment: @Mike Seymour:now I m getting the error as i edited the code. please suggest something on no rule to make target.

Comment: @user257489: It means what it says: your makefile is missing the rule needed to compile that file.

Comment: @MikeSeymour:  But I have added all the source files to the makefile so, which files more files needed to include